# Unable to start SQL server

Tags: mysql

I just downloaded MySQL and I tried to run it, and it gives the following error:

```
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: /usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysqld_safe: line 169: /usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: /usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.err: Permission denied
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.pid).
```

I referred to other StackOverflow posts, but the solutions do not seem to work for me, not sure where I am going wrong.

Further details:

- restarting gives me following error:
  `MySQL server PID file could not be found!`
- I tried deleting the .err file in `usr/local/mysql/data` but it did not help
- I cannot see any PID file in usr/local/mysql
- `/usr/local/var/` directory does not exist

Comment: what is the permission of this directory and its contents ? `/usr/local/var/mysql/`

Comment: Check also the hidden files. Possible .lock files created. And check the event  logs of your operation system.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question: I checked ```/usr/local/var/``` , but it does not exist, I will edit my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see you have a `Permission denied error` this error tells you that Mysql service does not have the proper permissions in order to modify the contents of `/usr/local/var/mysql`

```
./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.15/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: /usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.err: Permission denied
```

if you have created this path manually `/usr/local/var/mysql/` make sure that its permission is `mysql:mysql`. you can change it using the following command:

```
chown mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/ -R
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question: I checked ```/usr/local/var/``` , but it does not exist, I will edit my question now

Comment: @slal also could you post the content of /etc/my.cnf as this file may contain  the value `/usr/local/var` which you need to modify it to the correct path, by default it should be `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: I don't think I can find my my.cnf at this location ```/usr/local/var```. I tried at other locations as well suggested by another stack overflow answer: 
```/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf,
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf.
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf,
~/.my.cnf```

Comment: ok. what is the content ? are you still facing the issue or you have solved it ?

Comment: The file was not in any of the directories, so I figured something is wrong in the way mysql is installed ... so I deleted mysql and reinstalled and it after solving a few more errors, it did run. Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it